# Segmentation fault when reading space separated values from file in C

Tags: c, file, fopen, scanf

I have an input file which contains space separated values

```
AA BB 4
A B
AB BA
AA CC
CC BB
A B 3 
A C
B C
c B
```

I want content of the first line moved to `s1`, `s2` and `n` respectively
and next n lines contents 2 space separated strings these will move to 
`production_left` and `production_right` respectively.
The layout will be repeated for subsequent blocks of lines also.  The sample data has two blocks of input.

My code given below

```
int main()
{
    char *s1[20], *t1[20];
    char *production_left[20], *production_right[20];
    int n;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("suffix.txt","r");
    int iss=0;
    do{
         fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d",s1[iss],t1[iss],&n);
         int i=0;
         while(i<n)
         {
             fscanf(fp,"%s %s",production_left[i],production_right[i]);
             i++;
         }
    }while(!eof(fp));
}
```

Every time it is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: Hint `char *s1[20]` :  `s1` is an array of `char*`. And The pointer should actually point to the object when using it.

Comment: `eof` is used with file handle descriptors, not with streams. `feof` is used with streams, but does not work in the same way. One way to control your loop would be `while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d", s1[iss], t1[iss], &n) == 3) {...}` although there are other ways, such as `while(fgets(...) != NULL) { if sscanf(...) != 3) ... }`. The crucial point is always to check the return value from `scanf` function family.

Comment: `A B 3 A C` is a typo, isn't it?

Comment: @WeatherVane Well OP has fixed to 2-3 instead of 2-5 now. Don't worry.

Comment: From my first comment, passing `FILE*` to `eof` should have generated a compiler warning. Enable all warnings and do not ignore.

Comment: You have passed pointers to satisfy the format specs `%s`, which are *uninitialised* and so may or may not point to valid memory. Probably not, hence the seg fault. Ditto with other pointer arrays at the next `fscanf`. I would like to write this as an answer but there is a lot of other stuff wrong with the code, such as any attempt at essential error checking of I/O operations, or having compiler warnings enabled - and acted on. So I will leave this and other hints as comments.

Comment: Finally, because `i` is scoped in the `do-while` loop the program will not know how many items were read, after that loop completes.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of C, is just keeping clear in your mind, what data you need available in what scope (block) of your code. In your case, the data you are working with is the first (or header) line for each section of your data file. For that you have `s1` and `t1`, but you have nothing to preserve `n` so that it is available for reuse with your data. Since `n` holds the number of indexes to expect for `production_left` and `production_right` under each heading, simply create an index array, e.g. `int idx[MAXC] = {0};` to store each `n` associated with each `s1` and `t1`. That way you preserve that value for use in iteration later on. (`MAXC` is just a defined constant for `20` to prevent using **magic numbers** in your code)

Next, you need to turn to your understanding of pointer declarations and their use. `char *s1[MAXC], *t1[MAXC], *production_left[MAXC], *production_right[MAXC];` declares 4 *array of pointers* (`20` pointers each) for `s1`, `t1`, `production_left` and `production_right`. The pointers are **uninitialized and unallocated**. While each can be initialized to a *pointer value*, there is no *storage* (allocated memory) associated with any of them that would allow copying data. You can't simply use `fscanf` and assign the same pointer value to each (they would all end up pointing to the last value -- if it remained in scope)

So you have two choices, (1) either use a 2D array, or (2) allocate storage for each string and copy the string to the new block of memory and assign the pointer to the start of that block to (e.g. `s1[x]`). The `strdup` function provides the *allocate and copy* in a single function call. If you do not have `strdup`, it is a simple function to write using `strlen`, `malloc` and `memcopy` (use `memmove` if there is a potential that the strings overlap).

Once you have identified what values you need to preserve for later use in your code, you have insured the variables declared are scoped properly, and you have insured that each is properly initialized and storage allocated, all that remains is writing the logic to make things work as you intend.

Before turning to an example, it is worth noting that you are interested in *line-oriented input* with your data. The `scanf` family provides *formatted input*, but often it is better to use a *line-oriented* function for the actual input (e.g. `fgets`) and then a separate parse with, e.g. `sscanf`. In this case it is largely a wash since your first values are *string values* and the `%s` format specifier will skip intervening *whitespace*, but that is often not the case. For instance, you are effectively reading:

```
    char tmp1[MAXC] = "", tmp2[MAXC] = "";
    ...
    if (fscanf (fp, "%s %s %d", tmp1, tmp2, &n) != 3)
        break;
```

That can easily be replaced with a bit more robust:

```
    char buf[MAXC] = "", tmp1[MAXC] = "", tmp2[MAXC] = "";
    ...
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp) ||
        sscanf (buf, "%s %s %d", tmp1, tmp2, &n) != 3)
        break;
```

(which will validate both the read and the conversion separately)

Above, also note the use of temporary buffers `tmp1` and `tmp2` (and `buf` for use with `fgets`) It is very often advantageous to read input into temporary values that can be validated before final storage for later use.

What remains is simply putting the pieces together in the correct order to accomplish your goals. Below is an example that reads data from the filename given as the first argument (or from `stdin` if no filename is given) and then outputs the data and frees all memory allocated before exiting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 20

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *s1[MAXC], *t1[MAXC],
        *production_left[MAXC], *production_right[MAXC];
    int idx[MAXC] = {0},              /* storage for 'n' values */
        iss = 0, ipp = 0, pidx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* loop until no header row read, protecting array bounds */
    for (; ipp < MAXC && iss < MAXC; iss++) {
        char buf[MAXC] = "", tmp1[MAXC] = "", tmp2[MAXC] = "";
        int n = 0;

        if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp) ||
            sscanf (buf, "%s %s %d", tmp1, tmp2, &n) != 3)
            break;

        idx[iss] = n;
        s1[iss] = strdup (tmp1);    /* strdup - allocate & copy */
        t1[iss] = strdup (tmp2);

        if (!s1[iss] || !t1[iss]) { /* if either is NULL, handle error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: s1 or s1 empty/NULL, iss: %d\n", iss);
            return 1;
        }

        /* read 'n' data lines from file, protecting array bounds */
        for (int i = 0; i < n && ipp < MAXC; i++, ipp++) {
            char ptmp1[MAXC] = "", ptmp2[MAXC] = "";

            if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp) ||
                sscanf (buf, "%s %s", ptmp1, ptmp2) != 2) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: read failure, ipp: %d\n", iss);
                return 1;
            }
            production_left[ipp] = strdup (ptmp1);
            production_right[ipp] = strdup (ptmp2);

            if (!production_left[ipp] || !production_right[ipp]) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: production_left or "
                        "production_right empty/NULL, iss: %d\n", iss);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < iss; i++) {
        printf ("%-8s %-8s  %2d\n", s1[i], t1[i], idx[i]);
        free (s1[i]);  /* free s & t allocations */
        free (t1[i]);
        for (int j = pidx; j < pidx + idx[i]; j++) {
            printf ("  %-8s %-8s\n", production_left[j], production_right[j]);
            free (production_left[j]);  /* free production allocations */
            free (production_right[j]);
        }
        pidx += idx[i];  /* increment previous index value */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/production.txt
AA BB 4
A B
AB BA
AA CC
CC BB
A B 3
A C
B C
c B
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/production <dat/production.txt
AA       BB         4
  A        B
  AB       BA
  AA       CC
  CC       BB
A        B          3
  A        C
  B        C
  c        B
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block of memory, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/production <dat/production.txt
==3946== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3946== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3946== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3946== Command: ./bin/production
==3946==
AA       BB         4
  A        B
  AB       BA
  AA       CC
  CC       BB
A        B          3
  A        C
  B        C
  c        B
==3946==
==3946== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3946==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3946==   total heap usage: 18 allocs, 18 frees, 44 bytes allocated
==3946==
==3946== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3946==
==3946== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3946== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.